# How To Limit Hierarchical Pages Depth (For Custom Post Types) To Children Only

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical, child-pages

Is there a way to **limit the creation of pages** (custom post type) to a **specific depth** - e.g. level 1 (where 0 = parent, 1 = child, 2 = grand-child, etc.)?

For example, let's create a 'Summer' recipe page (custom post type: Recipe) with a slug '/summer'. Let's now create a 'Pie' page (a child of 'Summer') with a slug '/summer/pie'. I want to prevent the user from creating a page which is a child of 'Pie' or of any other sub-page.

- example.com/summer -> GOOD
- example.com/summer/pie -> GOOD
- example.com/summer/pie/apple -> BAD
- example.com/summer/pie/blackberry -> BAD

Thanks.

Comment: Please check: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667). A heck of an Answer, by @s_ha_dum :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function my_test($a) {
  $a['depth'] = 1;
  return $a;
}
add_action('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args','my_test');
```

Put that in a theme's function.php or in a plugin.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` hook. I'll try it and post back. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Yes, that works - thanks! I will point out to other interested people that this snippet ONLY restricts the user's ability to nest pages below depth X. This does not prevent existing pages (which have already been designated as children of children [of children of etc...]) from appearing in the list of pages in the admin console, nor from being publicly accessible via its URL. (This may or may not be the behaviour what you are looking for.)

Comment: @41st +1 actually has a button for it! The actual one is mine ;) This one is a [classic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923130/1287812)...!

Comment: @brasofilo Indeed there is. At the time I did not have the requisite reputation to actually +1 anything. However, I've now returned from Hogwarts to give proper credit to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The following filter shows only the top-level custom post type items in page attribute dropdowns (in main edit screen and in quick edit).
Replace the **'my_custom_post_type'** with your custom post type name.

```
function my_test($args) {
    global $post_type_object;

    if ( $post_type_object->name == 'my_custom_post_type') {
        $args['depth'] = 1;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args','my_test');
add_filter('quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'my_test');
```

Comment: I's looking for the `quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args` hook. Thanks for the snippet. <3